# Will paginate not paginating (instance variable error I suppose)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

H there, I can't get Will_paginate to paginate the photos a user has. See if someone can help me out with it...

My code is:

**Users Controller**

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @photos = @user.photos.paginate(:page => params[:page],:per_page => 6)
end
```

**Show Users View**

```
<div class="row center semi_padding_top semi_padding_">
   <%= will_paginate(@photos,:next_label => "<button class='semi_margin_right mediumbutton large-1 columns large-centered'>Más<i class='big icon-arrow-right2'></i></button>", :previous_label => "<button class='semi_margin_left mediumbutton large-1 columns large-centered'><i class='big icon-arrow-left'></i>Menos</button>", :page_links => false) %>
    </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Nope...It shows correctly the buttons and the url is correct:

users/11?page=1 , users/11?page=2, users/11?page=3...But still it's showing all of the photos in all of the pages instead of showing the 6 I've said to.

Comment: Could you show us where you are using `@photos`?

Comment: What do you mean with that? Im using it in the show method and in will_paginate div, is there something I'm missing?

Comment: There must be some place you're displaying the content of `@photos`, what you wrote in your question only displays the links to different pages right?